# Error presenting ViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

When attempting to perform this line, located in a separate function:

```
[self presentViewController:selectVC_ animated:YES completion:nil];
```

I receive this error:

> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayM insertObject:atIndex:]: object cannot be nil'

My declaration and instantiation are located in the same file

```
@class typesel_vc;
@interface
@property(nonatomic,strong)typesel_vc *selectVC;

@implementation 
@synthesize selectVC=selectVC_;

-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated{
    selectVC_=[[typesel_vc alloc]init];
}
```

Any thoughts on how to deal with this error?

EDIT:

Placed the allocation right before the actual line where I call presentViewController

```
selectVC_=[[typesel_vc alloc]init];
[self presentViewController:selectVC_ animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Comment: Could you please provide the call stack?

Comment: The problem is simple - at the time you call `presentViewController`, your `selectVC_` ivar is `nil`. You need to determine why.

Comment: You seem to be missing a class name after @interface in your code listing

Comment: @Rich Tolley the class name is not missing i just removed it make it easier to look at on StackOverflow...

Comment: At what point do you call `presentViewController` relative to the assignment to `selectVC_`?  Or more specifically, which occurs first?

Comment: I have edited the question with the code to show where the lines are relatively.

Comment: You may be chasing a red herring.  The error that you are receiving does not relate to the `presentViewController` message.  Are you adding your object to an array anywhere?

Comment: No but seems like the issue had to do with the VC being located on a storyboard

Answer (score 3):

First, class names by convention should start with a capital letter.

Second, it makes no sense to initialize a modal view controller to be presented in the future when a controller's view is loaded. You should do this just before you present it.

Third, from the code you posted the error cannot be determined. Use log statements and breakpoints to step through your code to see where the nil object comes up.

Comment: Everything you state here is good info but this really isn't an answer to the question. This doesn't answer why the crash is happening.

Comment: You did not include sufficient information. My answer provides the appropriate methods to resolve this common issue.

Comment: @rmaddy see the last paragraph - "from the code you posted the error cannot be determined"...

Comment: Sorry, yes, after a second reading I realize the 3rd paragraph does in fact offer thoughts on how to deal with the error. Never mind :)

Comment: The error comes up at this line: `[self presentViewController:selectVC_ animated:YES completion:nil];`

Comment: Storyboard was not mentioned in the question. With the breakpoints you would have found out that your VC was nil. I think you should check my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve this issue by modifying these lines of code:

```
selectVC_=[[typesel_vc alloc]init];
[self presentViewController:selectVC_ animated:YES completion:nil];
```

To:

```
selectVC_=[self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"typesel_vc"];
[self presentViewController:selectVC_ animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Comment: Interesting.  By passing nil to `presentViewController:animated:completion:` you should have gotten an `NSInvalidArgumentException - Application tried to present a nil modal view controller on target ..`.  Learn something every day.